# Barcode Missing When Printing

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, zebra-printers

Good Day!
I am facing a problem with Barcode Generate. It's working on my pc but barcode is missing in ZDesigner GT800 (EPL) Printer after printing. What should I do? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please, be more specific.. I can help you in this field but explain better our problem

Comment: What type of barcode is it, Code 39, Code 128, Code 11, or something else?  How is it encoded?  Are you manually encoding or using a .dll resource library such as Azalea or U2LBAR.DLL in Crystal Report?  Is the zebra printer connected to your computer where the barcode works, or is it another computer?  If its another computer, are the barcode fonts and/or reference libraries used installed on this computer?

Comment: I am using Code 39 and I don't know about encoding, May be it's manually encoding.  It's Zebra printer. Thanks for your cooperation & awaiting for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

Make sure what you are trying to barcode is within the * symbol (As in *BARCODE*).
Instead of using the barcode generator use Free 3of9 font and make sure that free3of9 is installed on the computer that you are trying to print from.